# Install wordpress without affecting clickfunnels

Tags: installation

I have a client that wants me to install wordpress to manage his main site. However he has clickfunnels redirecting his site to this page. How do I install wordpress without messing up his clickfunnels?

Comment: This is going to require clickfunnels specific knowledge to answer, it's not possible to answer this with just WP knowledge, it may not even require WP knowledge

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for the insight Tom